# Handle JSON response on the first GET request

Tags: javascript, json, get

I am trying to display a datagrid on the homepage. So the first GET request returns the data required in JSON and I need to process it to display in my grid.

My question is how would I handle this JSON response in the JS?

This is my workflow:

1. GET at `http://localhost/project/`
2. Process GET at server and return JSON
3. Received JSON response ***now how do I access it?***

I am using Spring MVC and I know I can pass this as a model attribute instead, but wanted to know if this is possible just using JS.

EDIT: If it helps, this is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Object> home(Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home!");
    List<Object> objects = dao.list();
    return objects;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Just realized how stupid this question is. I am mapping the ResponseBody to no view. Hence I can't process the response anywhere. I think my choices here are to intercept the get in the document body and instantiate another .get/.ajax call or to pass the JSON response as a model attribute the view. I am closing this - thanks everyone, appreciate the responses and for helping me realize my error.

Comment: Parse the string into an object with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Extremely simple but highly insecure method `var obj = eval(json_response)` will basically try to execute the json string, which is essentially syntactically valid javascript.

Comment: @Blender JSON.parse what? How do I get the ResponseBody object?

Comment: @MarcB: you forgot the "("++")" or "0||"+ brace-busting pads to ensure the eval sees an object.

Comment: @ganeshk how do you make your ajax request: with plain javascript using XMLHttpRequest or with jQuery ajax() call? Posting your code could help to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

You could always do an ajax call to get the JSON and then format it using Javascript.  jQuery has a pretty simple solution [jQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

**EDIT**

Sorry for missing that... on the first GET request, I would agree with @Blender using JSON.parse() and then use whatever HTML you need and append it to the page then.

Comment: This is before I can make an AJAX call. First GET request.

Comment: @Blender I must be missing something, but how is the first call an AJAX request?

Comment: how else would you call it?

Comment: Going to http://localhost/project/ in a browser - not doing $.ajax(url) or $.get(url)

Comment: @ganeshk: You send a GET request to `http://localhost/project/` with JavaScript and parse the response JSON into a JS object.